# Rest API in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This is certainly off the topic since it doesn't have the code but would appreciate if someone could give guidance.I am planning to implement modelling API of an analysis platform in shiny. The R script  has the code to invoke the other server to do the analysis and return the results to it. I then want that results to be displayed in Shiny. I just want to know whether it is possible in Shiny. I am going through Rest API in Shiny but it is quite confusing.

Comment: It appears that you just need a REST client in R to read the data. In that case things like https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html should work.

Comment: @warmoverflow: Thanks!